# Angular e2e testing. How to click dom elements ? (buttons links)

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-e2e

This is being done using angular 1.1.X

If there is a dom element that doesnt have a unique class or id how is one supposed to find it in order to do an element().click(); ?

is this something one would just use the full version of jquery for or is there a way to do it with angulars jqueryLite ?

ie if one has a list of links , how would you select the first element of the list using angular?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use generic jquery selectors to find elements.. here's some code from my e2e tests.  Note especially the :eq(3) selector for taking the 4th anchor tag.

```
    it('The cancel button should close the form and revert the info', function() {
        input("ci.customer.name").enter("Tom Selleck")
        element('#customerinfo input[value="Cancel"]').click();
        // check pdfdata to make sure it got reflected
        element('.navbar a:eq(3)').click();
        expect(element('.navbar a:eq(2)').text()).not().toBe("Customer (Tom Selleck)");
    });
```

Comment: I just checked and angular-scenario.js has a full version of jquery embedded in it.  (As opposed to the angular library itself)

Comment: is this using jquery lite or are you using the full version of jquery and if so where is the right place to add it?

Comment: I answered your question 15 seconds before you asked it.  That's service.

Comment: Just to clarify though, jquery lite only applies to the angular library, which is not used for running e2e tests.  The angular e2e library(angular-scenario) is a completely different beast  and embeds a full version of jQuery.

Comment: I know ! 

Is the right place to add it in the files areas of my karma-e2e.conf.js ?

Comment: ie will i be able to use it in the e2e testing? or not?

Comment: You don't need to change anything.  It should have access to all of jquery in e2e testing from the beginning.